# How to fliter the filtered items in sap.m.list

Tags: sapui5

I alredy have an sap.m.list which is already filtered based on one property.Now I again need to apply filter for that list to implement live search.

```
filterList:function(evt){
        debugger;
        var filters = [];
         var oFilter="";
        var query = evt.oSource.mProperties.value;
        if (query && query.length > 0) {
            var filter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("CLTYPE", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, query);
            filters.push(filter);

            var filter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("CLCAT", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, query);
            filters.push(filter1);
            var filter2 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("CLNUM", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, query);
            filters.push(filter2);

            oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter( filters, false );
        }


        // update list binding
        var list = sap.ui.getCore().byId("List");
        var binding = list.getBinding("items");
        binding.filter(oFilter);
    },
```

here  my list is already filtered.here list.getBinding('items') will give me all the items not the filtered Items.I applied filter for my sap.m.list as follows

```
     obj[filterParam] = context;

    var contextClauses=_.where(clauses,obj);
    sap.ui.getCore().getModel('ClauseModel').setProperty("/DATA/CURRENTCLAUSES",contextClauses);

// update list binding
var list = sap.ui.getCore().byId("List");
var binding = list.getBinding("items");
binding.filter(oFilter);
```

how to implement that??any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the 'and' condition in filter

```
 var mainFilter=new sap.ui.model.Filter(parameter,sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,context);
        var query =evt.getParameter("newValue");
        if (query && query.length > 0)var filter1= new sap.ui.model.Filter("CLNAME",sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,query);
            filtersArr1.push(filter1);
            filtersArr1.push(mainFilter);
          var filter2 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("CLNUM",sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, query);
            filtersArr2.push(filter2);
            filtersArr2.push(mainFilter);oFilter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter(filtersArr1,true);oFilter2 = new sap.ui.model.Filter(filtersArr2,true);filterGroup.push(oFilter1,oFilter2);oFilter4 = new sap.ui.model.Filter(filterGroup,false);
            binding.filter(oFilter4);
```

WORKING FINE

Answer (score 0):

Add `livechange` to your `textfield` and call a function to filter your list.

```
new sap.ui.commons.TextField({type:"Text",
        value:"",
        liveChange: function(oEvent){   
        //Now call a function to filter your list.                                       
        filterList(oEvent,oStorage.get("previousFilteredList"));
        }});
        filterList: function(oEvent,yourObj){  
                  var like = oEvent.getParameter("liveValue");  
                  var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("name",   
                  sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.StartsWith,like);  
                  var element = sap.ui.getCore().getElementById("sample");  
                  var listBinding = element.getBinding("items");  
                  listBinding.filter([oFilter]);  
  //Add the filtered object oStorage after every filter to access the previous filtered data
                //oStorage.put("previousFilteredList","yourobj");  
        }, 
    //Wherever you filter your data first.
    oStorage = jQuery.sap.storage("session");
    oStorage.put("previousFilteredList","yourobj");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.my problem is not how to call the filter function.I implemented livechange ofcourse.the problem is my list was already filtered and the line in filterlist  var listBinding = element.getBinding("items");   will give me the whole list items not filtered.I want the filtered list items to aplly filter again

Comment: try `session storage` to store your filtered data and use them as per your need anywhere. Check the edited answer above.

Comment: session storage is not so required.if i were able to retrive the filteredlistItems i can apply filter on them.the thing is how to retrive the filtered list items.like u have ur element variable r8? That is a list. Then how wil u retrieve the filtetred list items of that list? if that ques is answered my problem is solved as i can apply filter on that items.I dont know how to retrive the filteredlistitems.

Comment: Well that is because if you need that you need to re filter the existing `oFilter`  again and not the list as your list will always have same items each time you use it unless if you want to `set items and rebind it with list` with the new data time and again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options:

1. Apply the original filter and then the additional filters.
2. Make a new instance of the initially filtered list:

   ```
   // assumes you have declared lists (initialList and newList)
   // values between <..> should be replaced

    jQuery.each (initialList, function (index, item) {
        if (item.<someField> == <somevalue>) {
           // you could add an additional field to the new list item like so:
           item["<newFieldName"] = <newValue>;
           if (item.<someOtherField> >= <someOtherValue>) {    
                newList.push(item);       // adds this item to the new array / list
           }
         }
         newListModel.setData(newList);        // assumes newListModel has been created
         //bind to control
   ```

Comment: 2nd option doesnt work for me as I could not change the model bind to the list as I have to perform several operations with that model bind to the list.1st option is the required solution i guess.but how to implement that? when i try to implement the 2nd filter i tend to get all the items.how to do that?

Comment: Why not filter the initialList as above (instead of creating a new list) and then apply your additional filters.

Comment: I have solved the problem using 'and' condition  in filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var listFilter=new sap.ui.model.Filter(parameter,sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,context);
    var query =evt.getParameter("newValue");
    if (query && query.length > 0)
        var filter1= new sap.ui.model.Filter({
            new sap.ui.model.Filter("CLNAME",sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,query),
            new sap.ui.model.Filter("CLNUM",sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, query)}, and:false),
            var oFilter =  new sap.ui.model.Filter( [filter1,  listFilter], true)

            binding.filter(oFilter);
        });
```