# Filtering just a sap.m.List in Client Side SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I'm looking for filtering just a List in Client Side and let other like table etc etc   filtering in server side 
Is there any options to add to the list to filter in client side ?
Regards

Comment: [stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021484/how-to-fliter-the-filtered-items-in-sap-m-list) **Check the link, you may get any idea**

Comment: Use a JSON Model for filtering/sorting on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *operation mode* parameter for the v2.ODataModel. This parameter can be set at [model level](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html) (see the `defaultOperationMode` constructor parameter) or at [binding level](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding.html) (see the `operationMode` constructor parameter).

Based on this parameter, the model fetches data differently:

- **Server mode**: data is fetched as needed (paging, sorting and filtering is done on server side; each sorting, filtering or paging operation triggers a request).
- **Client mode**: the whole collection is requested initially. All sorting, filtering and paging operations are done on the client.
- **Auto**: a combination (based on other model settings).

To read more about the operation mode, check out the corresponding documentation: [OperationMode](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.OperationMode.html).

If you want to use this only on one list, then you should you the binding variant:

```xml
<List items="{path: '/Collection', parameters: {operationMode: 'Client'}}">
    <StandardListItem title="{Field}" />
</List>
```

Answer (score 0):

Serban is correct.
I just add one sample code so that you can refer when you want to change all your operation on model to client mode.
I looks like this:

```
var oModel = models.createODataModel({
        urlParametersForEveryRequest: [
            "sap-server",
            "sap-client",
            "sap-language"
        ],
        url: this.getMetadata().getConfig().serviceUrl,
        config: {
            metadataUrlParams: {
                "sap-documentation": "heading"
            },
            defaultOperationMode: sap.ui.model.odata.OperationMode.Client
        }
```

Pay attention to the property **defaultOperationMode**; you can change the mode by the property.

Cheer!